# Flutter - Not able to update or delete the managed products inside in app purchases?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

Currently, I am implementing in app purchase in flutter using the [FlutterInAppPurchase](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase#-example-tab-) Plugin.

I have 3 Items in my managed products my google play console like,

```
final List<String> _productLists = ['get_10_coins', 'get_100_coins', 'get_1000_coins']
```

Now, I am updated the details of the "get_10_coins" product but, It's not getting reflected in the app when i use FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getProducts(_productLists); method.

Then i deleted that product and added a new managed product like "get_50_coins". But, still it is showing me the old details of the "get_10_coins" product.

```
// fetching products using the following code
List<IAPItem> items = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getProducts(_productLists);
```

Can anyone tell me what can be the problem ? I have already uninstalled app as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the point.

As i have deleted the managed product "get_10_coins" from the google play console. But, i was querying the managed products using,

```
List<IAPItem> items = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getProducts(_productLists);
```

I didn't updated my _productLists = ['get_10_coins', 'get_100_coins', 'get_1000_coins'] from to _productLists = ['get_500_coins', 'get_100_coins', 'get_1000_coins']

So as play console was returning me the corresponding details of old product as play console keeps all the details of each products even if we delete it from the play console.